# Music stops during movie in Keynote

Tags: music, keynote, movie

I've inserted music into the presentation and the song is 5 mins long. There are 21 slides. After exporting the presentation to a movie, and then playing the movie, the song stops playing at 41 seconds, at about the 4th slide. It doesn't matter if I move the slides arounds - the music always stops at 41 secs when saved as a movie.

When I am in Keynote the song continues throughout if I play the presentation from the start. I want the music to play in the movie through all the slides.

The music file is 5 mins long. It is set to play continuously per slide.

Comment: who long is the actual music file? did you set it to play continuously or per slide?

Comment: The music file is 5 mins long. It is set to play continuously per slide. The movie automatically goes through about 4 slides and then the music stops. Any idea?

Comment: Do U trying another music file?

Comment: Thanks, lets get some details here: what version of Keynote, what version of QuickTime (assume you used GT to make the movie)

Comment: Keynote version 6.5 (2110), 2014. QuickTime Player version 10.4 (833), 2014. This error makes no sense. What is going on?

Comment: I did more research and discovered that Keynote 6.5 has a bug that causes this problem. I may have resolved this by going to File > Advanced > Change File Type > Package.

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to say that I have exactly the same problem. My music file is 2:10 and in the exported movie it always stops after 1:04... Maybe it's a bug? A possible workaround could be to add the audio file in imovie.

Comment: I'm trying....not sure how to combine this.

Comment: See above for possible fix.